# If $X=E[X\mid Y]$ what can we say about $X$ and $Y$.

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation

Suppose that we have two random variables $X,Y \in L^1$ such that:
$$
X=E[X\mid Y]
$$
what can we say about relationship between $X$ and $Y$?

Is $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Is $X$ and $Y$ uncorrelated?

There is converse(loosely speaking) of this statement that say if $X$, $Y$ are independent than  $E[X\mid Y]=E[X]$. So in my case $X$ would be a constant?

Comment: Note that a function of $Y$ can be uncorrelated with $Y$ (e.g. $Y^2$ where the distribution of $Y$ is symmetric about $0$), but can't be independent of $Y$ unless it is constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $E(X\mid Y=y)=\int x p(x\mid y) dx\implies\  E(X\mid Y)=g(Y)$ for some function $g$. Thus $X=E(X\mid Y)\implies X=g(Y)$. As an example, if  $X=Y,\ E(X\mid Y)=Y=X$

Comment: So, if we take a simple case $Y=X+Z$ where $Z$ is some other r.v. independent of $X$ than under my condition $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: How are they independent?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by how?

Comment: If $Y=X+Z$, $E(X|Y)=Y-E(Z|Y)\implies Z=E(Z|Y)$ so $Z$ is also either independent of $Y$ or as function of $Y$.

Comment: Sorry, you have to take it slow I am just learning this.  How did you get $E(X|Y)=Y-E(Z|Y)$?

Comment: I mean to say if $Y=X+Z$, then if $X\perp Z$, $Ee^{(aX+bY)}=Ee^{(a+b)X+bZ}=Ee^{(a+b)X}Ee^{bZ}\ne Ee^{aX}Ee^{bY}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21111/discussion-between-boby-and-samrat-mukhopadhyay).

Comment: Ok, sorry to hurry. I was referring to the fact that if two random variables are independent then their mgfs factor. For this case, it does not. And for the previous comment, since $Y=Z+X, X=E(X\mid Y)$, the conclusion followed.

Comment: Do you mind if we take it to the chat room? I have a few quick questions?

Comment: Okay. We'll discuss there.