# Upper bounds on $E[{\rm var}^2(X|Y)]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

I am looking for an upper bound on the quantity
\begin{align*}
E[{ \rm var}^2(X|Y)]
\end{align*}

where ${\rm var}(X|Y)=E[(X-E[X|Y])^2|Y]$.

Getting a lower bound is rather easy using Jensen's inequality
\begin{align*}
E[{ \rm var}^2(X|Y)] \ge E^2[{ \rm var}(X|Y)]= {\rm MMSE}^2(X|Y)
\end{align*}

If general upper bound does not exist then we can assume that $X$ is zero mean  unit varience and $Y=X+Z$ where $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and independent of $X$.
As an example, if $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ then we can actually compute $E[{ \rm var}^2(X|Y)]$ which is given by
\begin{align*}
{ \rm var}^2(X|Y)=\frac{1}{4}
\end{align*}

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  An upper bound on $\mathbb{E}[\text{Var}(X|Y)^2]$ only in terms of $Y$ (and maybe some property of the distribution of $X$) that works for general $X$?

Comment: Sorry, for confusion. I want it in term some property of $X$ that is not difficult to compute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}E[\rm{var}^2(X\mid Y)] := & E\left[\left(E[(X-E[X|Y])^2\mid Y]\right)^2\right]\\ \leq & E\left[E[(X-E[X|Y])^4\mid Y]\right] \\= & E[(X-E[X|Y])^4]\end{align}

The first inequality comes from Jensen applied on the conditional expectation inside. The last equality comes from iterated conditioning.

Comment: Is $E[(X-E[X|Y])^4]$ something easy to compute?

Comment: @Boby That depends on your definition of easy and the random variables $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Say $Y=X+Z$ where $E[X^2]=1$ and $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

Comment: @Boby You cannot compute the bound in my answer using that data alone. You need to say something about how $X$ and $Z$ are related (e.g. independence, measurability with respect to one another).

Comment: Yes, $X$ and $Z$ are independent. Also, an upper bound instead of computing is fine

Comment: @Calculun  Is $E[(X-E[X|Y])^4]$ related to Kurtosis?

Comment: @Boby If $X$ and $Y$ were independent, then yes. That is not the case here though.

Comment: Do you know whether quantity $E[(X-E[X|Y])^4]$ has been studied in liturature? If so could you point me to some sources

Comment: I am not aware of any existing works on this particular expectation. I wouldn't know how such a thing would be named either,

Comment: Maybe least mean fourth error "least mean fourth error"?? In any case take you very much. I will start a new question about this.

Comment: You are welcome and good luck.

Comment: But note that one of the questions you asked here previously is very relevant for your computation question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1146940/suppose-x-ex-mid-xz-where-x-and-z-are-independent?rq=1